# JQuery async xml GET request to WCF Restful service fails

Tags: wcf, jquery

I have a JQuery ajax function that is calling a my WCF Rest web service. My web service calls another service which returns JSON. I did not want to create all the C# classes and parse that JSON response and return it. So I just created a class with one string property in it and jammed the json as a string in that property and returning it as xml.

On the client side, I actually had the client working absolutely fine when I directly was calling the weather service and getting back JSON and enjoyed automatic parsing by JQuery. Now I changed the dataType to 'xml' and it is always going into the error function with no useful error message.

```
function getWeather(location) {
    var requestURL = 'http://localhost:55120/Weather1.svc/Weather/' + location;
    return $.ajax({
        url: requestURL,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'xml',
        error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
            hideWeatherDiv();
            var jsonVal = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
            $("#errorDiv").html('Response code: ' + xhr.status + '<br/>Response text: ' + jsonVal + '<br/>Status: ' +status + '<br/>Error thrown: ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}

var promise = getWeather(location);
promise.success(function (data) {
    alert('promise success');
    renderWeather(data);
    return;
});
```

Above are the function and my call to it. Like I mentioned, it is making request to my WCF service, which is calling the weather service. I can see the response in fiddler for my WCF request that it is valid XML, but I am unable to parse it here.